# How to fix could not use view or function because of binding errors

Tags: sql-server

I have Table-valued function when trying to execute I am getting below error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure IPTRate, Line 19 Invalid object
>   name 'DBName.dbo.AccessTable'. Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Could not use view or function 'dbo.ExchangeRate' because of binding
>   errors.

Actually the database name recently renamed from `DBName` to `DBNameNew`. Is the error because of database rename? how to fix this. please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: does the dbname in the query is required? are these cross database views? if all objects are in the same db and you happen to change dbname for whatever reason, then maybe you will have less troubles using [schema].[object] instead of [db].[schema].[object].

Answer (score 1):

Error message is clear..

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure IPTRate, Line 19 **Invalid object name 'DBName.dbo.AccessTable**

you will need to rename all the views

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's right I was about to post the answer. Sorry I did not looked the message